# No uWSGI alarm plugins when installed into a virtualenv with pip

Tags: plugins, pip, virtualenv

I've been attempting to use uWSGI alarm plugins in a virtualenv to no avail.

```
$ uwsgi --plugin plugins/alarm_xmpp --alarm "jabber xmpp:foo@example.com;password;bar@example.com"
open("plugins/alarm_xmpp_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3659]
plugins/alarm_xmpp_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.7 (64bit) on [Wed Oct 22 15:23:59 2014] ***
invalid alarm: jabber xmpp:foo@example.com;password;bar@example.com
```

Apparently the culprit is [a missing plugin.](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/alarm.c##L293-L294)

Looking at the output of `pip install uwsgi` reveals that many, but not all, plugins are linked statically to the uwsgi binary. The remaining ones are apparently never even built.

What can I do to enable all the `plugin/alarm_*` plugins?

1. Are the missing plugins available in PyPI? Neither `pip search` nor Google turn up any packages that might contain the required files.
2. Can I edit the uWSGI build configuration after pip has downloaded the source package but before it has been built?
3. Is there another way to build and install the plugins inside the virtualenv?
4. Failing everything above, is there a way to build and install the plugins outside the virtualenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uWSGI binary is able to build plugins by itself:

`uwsgi --build-plugin <dir>`

where 'dir' is the directory containing the plugin. The procedure will end with a .so file you can load with --plugin

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably edit your answer and add some details as soon as I have time.